# What is the correct way to measure DC power at the input of a multilevel inverter in a Simulink simulation?

Tags: voltage, power, current, matlab, input

I modelled a 11 level cascaded multilevel inverter, and I would like to measure the power at the input of the inverter, so I do not know how to properly evaluate the actual input power of that inverter for each H-bridge, as I know it's just V * I, but here I have 5 sources. Could someone give me some light?
thanks

[image]

Comment: I would multiply the *average* input current of each dc source and multiply by its value (\$P_{in}=V_{dc}I_{in,avg}\$) then sum up all 5 results. Does this lead to a meaningful result considering the power you deliver?

Comment: @VerbalKint Does this lead to a meaningful result considering the power you deliver?
I do  not  understand  your  question, by the way, I want  to  calculate  the  input  power  because  I want  to  get the  efficiency %

Comment: I know, my question was just to check that if you calculate the efficiency by summing up the input powers, you have an efficiency figure that makes sense, like 0.96 for instance and not 0.5 or 1.2 : ) That being said, the final calculation may be different when you have a single dc source as all current contributors may combine differently to form a single average value.

Comment: No, not by summing up just the input powers. To calculate the efficiency, I must calculate the dc output power after using the rectifier to obtain DC current and voltage.


Still have some points, PLZ .

1- Can I use the mean block by using the switching frequency that I used to get the average current of each DC source?

2-  So the dc input power will be    Ptotal= Pin1+Pin2+Pin3+Pin4+Pin5.

Comment: I would use a single dc source referenced to GND and then use 5 voltage-controlled voltage sources feeding each bridge. The current in each floating dc source is then brought back to the main ground-referenced dc source (using current-controlled current sources), naturally summing them up at one point. The total average current multiplied by the ground-referenced dc source would then be the average input power you want.

Comment: @VerbalKint  thanks for your response  Sir, may you provide more explanation please cause did not get it, how to get the average of it?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it in SPICE: distribute a main ground-referenced dc source via floating voltage-controlled voltage sources and then reflect each individual current to this source:

[image]

Then measure the input current via a dummy source (a 0-V source in SPICE), average the current and multiply by the input source dc voltage: you have the average input power.

Comment: here seems like one dc source. and in the multilevel inverter, each H-bridge must have a separated dc source.  And may I know  what is  this  block  above V1 SOURCE

Comment: It seems you are not familiar with SPICE symbols: the E-sources are voltage-controlled sources and duplicate the dc input voltage in a floating way. Then, current measurement is performed through a 0-V dc source, a classic in SPICE. You could also measure the current in V, same result.

Comment: yes, I did not work on SPIC so far. as in my question, it is a different converter.
and in Matlab, the voltage control source block includes THREE ports [+ - and S]. 
also my inquiry regarding the elements above of  V1? What is that element? is it mean block to get the average value? thanks

Comment: The symbol above V1 is a dummy 0-V source used to measure the instantaneous current. When you have it, simply average it.

Comment: As I know a dummy 0-V source is not available in MatLab.